# error in streaming twitter data to Hadoop using flume

Tags: hadoop, twitter, streaming, flume

I am using Hadoop-1.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04

I am trying to stream data from twitter to HDFS by using Flume-1.6.0. I have downloaded flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and included it in flume/lib folder. I have set path of flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar as FLUME_CLASSPATH in conf/flume-env.sh . This is my flume agent conf file:

```css
#setting properties of agent
Twitter-agent.sources=source1
Twitter-agent.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks=sink1

#configuring sources
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.type=com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.channels=channel1
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerKey=<consumer-key>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.consumerSecret=<consumer Secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessToken=<access Toekn>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.accessTokenSecret=<acess Token Secret>
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.keywords= morning, night, hadoop, bigdata

#configuring channels
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.type=memory
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.capacity=10000
Twitter-agent.channels.channel1.transactionCapacity=100

#configuring sinks
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.channel=channel1
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.type=hdfs
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.path=flume/twitter/logs
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollSize=0
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.rollCount=1000
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.batchSize=100
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.fileType=DataStream
Twitter-agent.sinks.sink1.writeFormat=Text
```

when I run this agent, I am getting an error like this:

```css
15/06/22 14:14:49 INFO source.DefaultSourceFactory: Creating instance of source source1, type com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
15/06/22 14:14:49 ERROR node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider: Unhandled error
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.conf.Configuration.isStallWarningsEnabled()Z
 at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.<init>(TwitterStreamImpl.java:60)
 at twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory.<clinit>(TwitterStreamFactory.java:40)
 at com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource.<init>(TwitterSource.java:64)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
 at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
 at org.apache.flume.source.DefaultSourceFactory.create(DefaultSourceFactory.java:44)
 at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSources(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:322)
 at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:97)
 at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
 at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My flume/lib folder already has `twitter4j-core-3.0.3.jar`

How do I rectify this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this issue. As flume-sources-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar and twitter4j-stream-3.0.3.jar contains the same FilterQuery.class, there arises a jar conflict. All twitter4j-3.x.x uses this class so it would be better to download twitter jars of version 2.2.6([twitter4j-core](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core),[twitter4j-stream](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-stream),[twitter4j-media-support](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-media-support))  and replace 3.x.x with these newly downloaded jars under flume/lib directory.

Run the agent again and twitter data will be streamed to HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

Change
Twitter-agent.sources.source1.type=com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
with 
TwitterAgent.sources.Twitter.type = org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource

Comment: Can you explain your answer and/or provide further information?